# Image library for vs2010 express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, image, imagemagick

I'm looking for image library working under vs2010. I tried imagemagick (and its api magick++) but that requires building it from scratch which is undesireable.

It doesn't have to be as advanced as imagemagick. I need it to open most popular image files and convert them to raw array of RGB888 or RGB565 data.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to switch to C# and use it's internal Image class. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download Magick++
http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/
Under the heading, “Obtaining Magick++”, follow the “ftp” link then choose a download mirror for wherever you live. You should now see an ftp listing if you didn’t go to sourceforge or somewhere like that. Scroll down and click on the “binaries” directory and I downloaded “ImageMagick-6.8.6-9-Q16-x86-dll.exe” (6.8.6-9 was the current version at the time).

Step 2: Install Magick++
Run the .exe and next, next, next until you get to the screen below and make sure to select “install development headers for C and C++.” Also make sure to note the install path because we need that later.

Finish the installation and launch Visual Studio 2010.

Step 3: Adding Magick++ to a project
Open your project properties and at the top, set the Configuration to “All configurations” or Release(Active).
Magick++ doesn’t like to run in Visual Studio’s Debug mode so you have to build as a Release or ImageMagick won’t be happy.

In the project properties list on the left side, expand

Configuration Properties->General
Add the ImageMagick Include folder as an Additional Dependency. This is where you need to know where you installed ImageMagick too.
Next select “Code Generation” under the C/C++ section on the left sidebar of the project properties and ensure that “Runtime Library” is “Multi-Threaded (/MT)”

Expand the “Linker” section under C/C++ and add the lib directory for ImageMagick as an Additional Dependency (like in the image above, just “lib” instead of “include.”

Almost there.. now click on “Input” under the Linker section on the left sidebar. Add one more Additional Dependency and add these:

CORE_RL_magick_.lib CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib CORE_RL_wand_.lib

Step 4: Adding the header and namespace

namespace identifiers and you should be good to go!